# Sharing internet connection with WDS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wds

Is it possible to share an internet connection through WDS? I'm on the very edge of a wireless network, the spot that I'm in maintains a stable 22% according to XP with the help of a parabolic reflector crafted from a cheap pie tin. I was thinking I could grab another wireless router, use WDS to bridge the this router with the other one and share the 'net connection through it thus giving me a little bit more freedom but when I tried it it didn't work. WDS looks like it bridged the networks just fine, but I couldn't access anything on the internet. Do I need to do anything special or is this just not possible?

Comment: You may just want to try it and troubleshoot as you go.  Can't hurt.  Is it possible to wire the routers together and use router B as wireless hub?

Comment: No, they're too far apart. I'm trying to share an internet connection this way, I should've mentioned that earlier. I did try it and it didn't work, no 'net access from anything behind router B.

Comment: @cornjuliox, *Is it possible* is a pretty vague question.  What specific problems are you having or are you questioning?

Comment: I enable WDS on router B and enter the connection details (key, SSID, etc) for router A. neither router is running anything other than the stock firmware. I don't get any internet access through anything connected to router B, but 'net access for machines connected to router A is fine.

Comment: Are you able to reach(ie ping) computer connected to router A from one connected to router B?  Can router B ping router A?  What kind of routers do you have?  What IP address do they have?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I didn't change the routers' default IP addresses so they BOTH had 192.168.1.1 as an IP. Perhaps this is what's causing my problems? One router is a TP-LINK router that supports WDS out of the box, and the other is a Linksys, I forgot the exact model number but I'm sure its the one everyone likes to use with DD-WRT but I can't really change the firmware on the Linksys as its not my router.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.  I have done this configuration with both the [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) and [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/firmware) firmwares on on a [Linksys WRT54GL](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/WRT54GL).  In my particular configuration I had a WRT54G acting as the router connected to the internet and my WRT54GL was bridging the connection to a couple of devices that I had wired to the WRT54GL.

I am no longer using this configuration, but I did have it running for over a year so I know that it works.  I don't know if any of the stock firmwares support it, so you may have to install a 3rd part firmware on the router in order to get this feature.

Comment: Make sure your router is [supported](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#what_will_this_run_on), you don't want to brick it. [Here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) for DD-WRT.

Comment: Most modern router support wireless bridging now ;) I got a WBR-1310 that cost 30$ here an he support it right out of the box ;)